# How to assign a string value to the Float Data Type Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of data type Float in a stored proc. If that column doesn't have data in DB, then I have to assign '--' and return the results.

I tried like this, but getting "Converting data type varchar to float."

```
 ISNULL(ABCColumn, '--') as ABCColumn.
```

Here ABCColumn is Float Data type. Is there a way to do this??

Comment: A result set column must be of a single data type, here you try to return both float and character - which can't be done. Either `cast` your float to char, or fix it in the presentation layer.

Comment: Try something like `coalesce(cast(ABCColumn as varchar(10)), '--')`.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT CAST(11.35 AS FLOAT) AS Num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS Num
)
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(Num AS VARCHAR), '--') AS NumString
FROM CTE
```

WITH CTE is used just to produce some dummy data; Num column is converted to a string (to align with '--' data type); ISNULL is applied on data with the same type

Comment: can I use this in the select query on a particular column in SP?

Comment: Tim, I am not sure I understand the question.

Comment: what I mean is - Can I use your logic on a particular column in a select query?

Comment: Like My Select query looks like...   select A, B, C, D, ABCColumn,XYZ from Temptable. so I want to check for Null value on ABCColumn and if it has null, then I have to assign '--'.   FYI: ABCColumn data type is float.

Comment: Tim, you can do this:
`SELECT A, B, C, D, ...  ISNULL(CAST(ColX AS VARCHAR), '--') AS NumString
FROM YourTable`

Comment: seems like this works. Let me add in my proc and see.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can simply put

```
ISNULL(ABCColumn, '0') as ABCColumn.
```

In front end, you can validate.
if `ABCColumn` is `0` means you can put whatever you wants..

Or Else

Use `TRY_CAST`

```
ISNULL(ABCColumn, TRY_CAST('--' AS DECIMAL)) as ABCColumn.
```

OR

```
ISNULL(CAST(@ABCColumn AS NVARCHAR), '--' ) as ABCColumn
```

Comment: I tried this  ISNULL(ABCColumn, TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL , '--')) as ABCColumn. but still getting Null (if no data is available). but expected is '--'.

Comment: Then you can convert Decimal Column in to Varchar, Not an value

Comment: ISNULL(CAST(@ABCColumn AS NVARCHAR), '--' ) as ABCColumn

Answer (score 0):

This is a single expression:

```
ISNULL(ABCColumn, '--') as ABCColumn
```

It returns a single type.  But what type?  Does it return a number because one value is a number?  Or a string?

In this case, `ISNULL()` returns a float because the first argument is a float.

The rules are explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-types).

The solution is to ensure that both values are strings.  I also have a preference for `COALESCE()` (because it is the standard function).  So:

```
COALESCE(CAST(ABColumn as VARCHAR(255)), '--') as ABCColumn
```